# Creating and Adding Unlimited Objects into an Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, object, arraylist, data-structures

For example, I have an object called Patient. I will have unknown numbers of Patient in a day and have to store these patients records for a week.

1. I will have an object array to store "patient" in a day
2. A weekArray of size 7 to store each day record?

I am quite brain stuck on how to proceed with this. How do i create unlimited object (e.g. Patient patient1, patient2 ... ) until user wants to skip to next day and store them in an unlimited size of array?

```
struct Patient {
  string name; 
  int age;
}

void main (){

/*Im not sure the type for this array and how to assign these patients into this array daily*/ 
?? weekArray [7];
bool continueAdd = true;

  for (int i =0; i<7; i++){
    while (continueAdd){

      //Prompt creation of new object using Patient as object type
      Patient patient1....patientN //I want to only create new object after user wants to add another patient at the end of this loop

      cout<<"Enter name:";
      cin>> ??.name;
      cout<<"Enter age:";
      cin>> ??.age;

      cout<<"Continue adding patient? Y for yes, N to skip to next day";
      char decision;
      cin>>decision;
      if (decision == 'n'){
         continueAdd=false;
      } //assume i hv tolower.

      }
  }
}
```

I hope it is not that confusing as to what i am asking. I think I will need to use arrayList instead of dynamic array. I was hoping if someone could guide me the structure of how to proceed with this.

Or if there is any way to solve this more efficiently, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You should use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Comment: The assignment as condition `decision = 'n'` looks weird.

Comment: Dear tear, the whole subject of containers in C++ are created to deal with this kind of problems! please have a look at them and save your self so much time!

Comment: @MikeCAT for the adding unknown number of patients in a day only? or for the array that store 7 days worth of data as well.

Comment: "7 days" is fixed, so you can choose either one you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) when the number of elements to store is unknown.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

struct Patient {
  string name; 
  int age;
};

int main (){
  std::vector<Patient> weekArray[7];

  for (int i =0; i<7; i++){
    bool continueAdd = true;
    while (continueAdd){

      //Prompt creation of new object using Patient as object type
      Patient patient;

      cout<<"Enter name:";
      cin>> patient.name;
      cout<<"Enter age:";
      cin>> patient.age;

      //Add this object to the array
      weekArray[i].push_back(patient);

      cout<<"Continue adding patient? Y for yes, N to skip to next day";
      char decision;
      cin>>decision;
      if (decision == 'n'){
         continueAdd=false;
      } //assume i hv tolower.

      }
  }
}
```

Also note that:

- You need `;` after structure declaration.
- Global `main` must return `int` in C++.
- You will have to initialize `continueAdd` before each loop for each day in the week.
- `=` is an assignment operator. You should use `==` to check equality.

These notes are also applied to the above code.

Comment: ah thank you!! Using this vector, I dont have to "create a new object" ? As in in manual, we usually do this, Patient patient1, patient2 ... etc;

Comment: @tear `weekArray[i].push_back(patient);` creates a new object at the end of the array and data in `patient` will copied to the new object.

Comment: ahh okay!! I will try your suggestion when I am free. Tqsm !!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but how do i call / ref a specific patient? For example, I want to display the name of the third patient in Day 2

Comment: @tear The third patient in Day 2 is `weekArray[1][2]`, so its name is `weekArray[1][2].name`. Note that array indice start from 0.